# oracle dba_identifiers missing data

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, metadata

I have full rights on the dba_identifiers table and am trying to link this to dba_procedures and dba_arguments (yes l, I know don't use dba tables). My question is that one user's package identifier information is missing from the dba_identifiers table. It has permission on the dba_identifiers table but I think that isn't the issue.

Does anybody know whether, this dba_identifiers table doesn't always capture system metadata for packages. I am using this to try to identify whether an object is a function/procedure/type etc

Comment: Why don't you use dba_objects, if you only need to identify the object type?

Comment: Hi, there is a bug, documented by oracle. When I am back from my ski holiday I will share it on this forum. Dba_objects makes no difference.

Comment: @ZakWillis have you ever came back from holiday?

Answer (score 2):

To get information into `DBA_IDENTIFIERS`, the object must be compiled with the correct settings.

Try:

```
alter session set plscope_settings = 'identifiers:all'
alter package my_schema.my_package compile;
```

And then look in `DBA_IDENTIFIERS` for the missing information.